# how to get the count showing up iper week

Tags: mysql, sql

The table shows the car plate number, showing time, location of cameras. I need to find the cars who show up in every week for more than once, I need to know who are they and the showing frequency for each week, and the total number of the cars that fulfill the conditions.

I tried to split the time period manually, but that's too inefficient.
I tried the following query:

```
   SELECT *, 
       Variance(Time_to_sec(time)), 
       Count(*) 
   FROM   trafficdata.anpr_in 
   WHERE  location = 'a35.1.ob.1' 
       AND Date(time) BETWEEN '2012-05-09'AND '2012-05-15' 
       AND Time(time) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '07:05:00' 
   GROUP  BY plate 
   HAVING ( Count(plate) > 3 );
```

The input table looks like:

```
  plate         location     number                    time
T971JUR     A3024.7.IB.1         96     2012-05-13 18:06:17
HN52YWE     A3024.13.OB.1        94     2012-05-13 18:09:53
```

Comment: Can you create an example in sqlfiddle?  sometimes while creating the example your doubt gets clarified

Comment: the whole time period is 2012/05/09-201209/19. i want to know in this period, how many cars are showing everyweek more than once. and i need to find who are they. and i know i can add the time limit in query showing above. but it wastes too much time. i want to do it by mysql, and get weekly results automatically.

Comment: What are your tables? only one table as explained above?

Answer (score 1):

if your table is

```
create table tickets (car_number varchar(10),date_of_offense date, 
camera_number varchar(10));
```

then

```
select car_number from tickets group by week(date_of_offense ) having count(*)>1
```

would get you those cars who have offended twice or more in a week

Comment: i have added the table above. i have already got the table. do you mean   i need to create another table?

Comment: No... I was explaining it with a create table just so that the structure I have worked on is clear, if you have the table, then you can just use the select

Answer (score 1):

When you say "I need to find the cars who show up in every week for more than once", do you mean:  cars who show up in one week more than once? Or, cars who show up in every week during the period more than once?

The first can be answered as:

```
SELECT plate, week(time), count(*)
FROM   trafficdata.anpr_in 
WHERE  location = 'a35.1.ob.1' AND
       Date(time) BETWEEN'2012-05-09'AND '2012-05-15' AND
       Time(time) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '07:05:00' 
GROUP  BY plate , week(time)
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

The second can be answered as:

```
select plate
from (SELECT plate, week(time), count(*) as cnt
      FROM   trafficdata.anpr_in 
      WHERE  location = 'a35.1.ob.1' AND
             Date(time) BETWEEN'2012-05-09'AND '2012-05-15' AND
             Time(time) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '07:05:00' 
      GROUP  BY plate , week(time)
      HAVING count(*) > 1
     ) t
having min(plate) > 1;
```

Comment: each week for more than once